# Extracting datas from Oracle database

Tags: c#, database, oracle, visual-studio, export

i need your expertise on my code :)

Here is what i wrote:

```
public List<List<string>> ExecuteSelectPPRD(string query, string C1, string C2, string C3, string C4, string C5)
    {
        List<List<string>> result = new List<List<string>>();

        try
        {
            using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(oradbPPRD))
            {
                conn.Open();
                using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(query, conn))
                {
                    OracleDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

                    if (reader.HasRows)
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                            {
                                List<string> thisRow = new List<string>();
                                thisRow.Add((string)reader[C1]);
                                thisRow.Add((string)reader[C2]);
                                thisRow.Add((string)reader[C3]);
                                thisRow.Add((string)reader[C4]);
                                thisRow.Add((string)reader[C5]);
                                result.Add(thisRow);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("No rows found.");
                    }
                    reader.Close();
                }
                conn.Dispose();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

        return result;
    }
```

When i call this function, it's like the "foreach" part doesn't work. In fact, the foreach is ignored and i'd like to know why because everything seems logical to me as it is.

The goal is to extract a table from an oracle database, who contains 5 columns and i know their name, but i don't know the number of lines. Then i export it in an excel file (this part works in an other function, and no problems for this part for now)

Thanks in advance for you comments

Comment: "foreach" part doesn't work because DataTable has 0 rows.

Comment: So it *does* work :) @AbdellahOUMGHAR

Comment: Yes i think so too, but why doesn't it see it? i checked on the database and when i execute the query, there are a lot of them...

Comment: Because it never gets filled. See my answer @RomainG

Comment: you just create a new instance for DataTable, and any Data not assign to DataTabel

Comment: You must remove a foreach Bloc or you can assign data to DataTable and remove while bloc

Answer (score 0):

Your `foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)` is useless. It iterates over an empty data table while you are actually reading a data reader.

Your `while` is enough to keep the data reader advancing to the new row. Just remove the `foreach`.

Comment: I tested and indeed it worked, i didn't think that the reader would indersand that there are rows. Last error, for a reason that i don't now yet it exports me only 6 rows on my excel file out of 120 in the database. Thank you :)

Comment: We can't know since you didn't post the query or any other related information. For your new problem: please ask a new question. Include the table layout, the data in it, the SQL statement and your actual result.

Comment: I know i'll try to figure it out myself and if i'm stuck i'll do another post. Thank you again